# Nginx upstream gets timed out

Tags: nginx, apache2

I am running hestia with Apache2 and Nginx and i get a lot of "**upstream timed out**" and i wonder if anyone can see in my config how to fix it ? the server is Epyc 72 with 6 core and 16GB ram

I am running hestia with Apache2 and Nginx and i get a lot of "**upstream timed out**" and i wonder if anyone can see in my config how to fix it ? the server is Epyc 72 with 6 core and 16GB ram

**NGINX**

```
# Server globals
user                    www-data;
worker_processes        auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile    65535;
error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid                     /run/nginx.pid;

include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

# Worker config
events {
        worker_connections  3024;
        use                 epoll;
        multi_accept        on;
}

http {
    # Main settings
    sendfile                        on;
    tcp_nopush                      on;
    tcp_nodelay                     on;
    client_header_timeout           180s;
    client_body_timeout             180s;
    client_header_buffer_size       2k;
    client_body_buffer_size         256k;
    client_max_body_size            256m;
    large_client_header_buffers     4 8k;
    send_timeout                    60s;
    keepalive_timeout               30s;
    keepalive_requests              100000;
    reset_timedout_connection       on;
    server_tokens                   off;
    server_name_in_redirect         off;
    server_names_hash_max_size      512;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size   512;
    charset                         utf-8;

    # FastCGI settings
    fastcgi_buffers                 4 256k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size             256k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size       256k;
    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size    256k;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout         30s;
    fastcgi_read_timeout            2400s;
    fastcgi_send_timeout            180s;
    fastcgi_cache_lock              on;
    fastcgi_cache_lock_timeout      5s;
    fastcgi_cache_background_update on;
    fastcgi_cache_revalidate        on;
    
    # Proxy settings
    proxy_redirect                  off;
    proxy_set_header                Host $host;
    proxy_set_header                X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header                X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass_header               Set-Cookie;
    proxy_buffers                   32 4k;
    proxy_connect_timeout           180s;
    proxy_read_timeout              3600s;
    proxy_send_timeout              180s;

    # Log format
    log_format  main    '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] $request '
                        '"$status" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                        '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    log_format  bytes   '$body_bytes_sent';
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;

    # Mime settings
    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Compression
    gzip                on;
    gzip_static         on;
    gzip_vary           on;
    gzip_comp_level     6;
    gzip_min_length     1024;
    gzip_buffers        16 8k;
    gzip_http_version   1.1;
    gzip_types          text/plain text/css text/javascript text/js text/xml application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml application/xml+rss application/x-font-ttf image/svg+xml font/opentype;
    gzip_proxied        any;
    gzip_disable        "MSIE [1-6]\.";

    # Cloudflare https://www.cloudflare.com/ips
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/cloudflare.inc;

    # SSL PCI compliance
    ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:20m;
    ssl_session_timeout 60m;
    ssl_buffer_size     1400;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers         "ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS";
    ssl_dhparam         /etc/ssl/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ecdh_curve      secp384r1;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    resolver 8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8 127.0.0.53  valid=300s ipv6=off;
    resolver_timeout    5s;

    # Error pages
    error_page 403 /error/404.html;
    error_page 404 /error/404.html;
    error_page 410 /error/410.html;
    error_page 500 501 502 503 504 505 /error/50x.html;

    # Proxy cache
    proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=2 keys_zone=cache:10m inactive=60m max_size=1024m;
    proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
    proxy_temp_path  /var/cache/nginx/temp;
    proxy_ignore_headers Expires Cache-Control;
    proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_502;
    proxy_cache_valid any 1d;

    # FastCGI cache
    fastcgi_cache_path /var/cache/nginx/micro levels=1:2 keys_zone=microcache:10m max_size=1024m inactive=30m;
    fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
    fastcgi_cache_methods GET HEAD;
    fastcgi_cache_use_stale updating error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_503;
    fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
    add_header X-FastCGI-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

    # Cache bypass
    map $http_cookie $no_cache {
        default 0;
        ~SESS 1;
        ~wordpress_logged_in 1;
    }

    # File cache (static assets)
    open_file_cache          max=10000 inactive=30s;
    open_file_cache_valid    60s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors   off;

    # Wildcard include
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/domains/*.conf;
}
```

**APACHE2**

```
# It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
# below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
#
#   /etc/apache2/
#   |-- apache2.conf
#   |   `--  ports.conf
#   |-- mods-enabled
#   |   |-- *.load
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   |-- conf.d
#   |   `-- *

# Global configuration
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 2400
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 800
KeepAliveTimeout 10

<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers         40
    MinSpareServers      50
    MaxSpareServers      100
    ServerLimit         256
    MaxClients          1200
    MaxRequestsPerChild 4000
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          200
    MaxRequestsPerChild 4000
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          200
    MaxRequestsPerChild 4000
</IfModule>

# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
#User www-data
#Group www-data

AccessFileName .htaccess

<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Files>

DefaultType None
HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
Include mods-enabled/*.load
Include mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on and which to use for name based vhosts
Include ports.conf

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%a %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%a %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
LogFormat "%b" bytes

IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
IncludeOptional conf.d/domains/webmail.*.conf
IncludeOptional conf.d/domains/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
#Include sites-enabled/

ErrorDocument 403 /error/403.html
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /error/50x.html
ErrorDocument 501 /error/50x.html
ErrorDocument 502 /error/50x.html
ErrorDocument 503 /error/50x.html
ErrorDocument 506 /error/50x.html
```